# new line in tikz in latex

Tags: tikz-pgf, equations, line-breaking, line, formulas

I have wrote this code to explan determinant of matrix using tikz package. How can I write last formulas in new line?

```
  \documentclass{article}
  \usepackage{tikz}
  \usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta}
   \usetikzlibrary{matrix}
   \usepackage{fullpage,amsmath}

 \begin{document}

    \tikzset{node style ge/.style={circle}}

    \tikz  \node[scale=1] {
    \(
    \begin{tabular}{|ccc|}
        $y$ & $y^{\prime}$ & $y^{\prime\prime}$  \\
        $e^{-t}$ & $-e^{-t}$ & $e^{-t}$     \\
        $e^t$ & $e^t$ & $e^t$ \\
    \end{tabular}=
    \)  
    \begin{tikzpicture}[baseline=(A.center)]    
        \matrix (A) [matrix of math nodes, nodes = {node style ge},,column sep=0 mm] 
        { y & y^{\prime} & y^{\prime\prime}& y & y^{\prime} \\
            1 & -1 & 1 & 1 & -1 \\
            1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 \\
        };
        
        \draw[->] (A-3-1.south west) -- (A-1-3.north east)node [xshift=0.1cm, yshift=0cm] {-};
        
        \draw[->] (A-3-2.south west) -- (A-1-4.north east)node [xshift=0.1cm, yshift=.1cm] {-};
        \draw[->] (A-3-3.south west) -- (A-1-5.north east)node [xshift=0.1cm, yshift=0cm] {-};
        \draw[->] (A-1-1.north west) -- (A-3-3.south east)node [xshift=0.1cm, yshift=-.1cm] {+};
        \draw[->] (A-1-2.north west) -- (A-3-4.south east)node [xshift=0.1cm, yshift=-.1cm] {+};
        \draw[->] (A-1-3.north west) -- (A-3-5.south east)node [xshift=0.1cm, yshift=-.1cm] {+};
        
        \draw[black] (A-1-1.north west) -- (A-3-1.south west);
        \draw[black] (A-1-4.north west) -- (A-3-4.south west);
    \end{tikzpicture}
    \newline
    
    \(
    =(-y+y^{\prime}+y^{\prime\prime})-(-y^{\prime\prime}+y+
    y^{\prime}) =0$$$$\Rightarrow y^{\prime\prime}=y
    \)
    
};
\end{document}
```

Comment: Unrelated: In math mode `'` is the same as `^\prime` with the added bonus that several `''` assumulates into `^{\prime\prime}` so no need to write that much

Comment: I'd just use `\(
    =\begin{aligned}[t]
      (-y+y'+y'')-(-y''+y+y')=0
      \\
      \Rightarrow y^{\prime\prime}=y
    \end{aligned}
    \)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `align*` for this purpose. A few other changes:

- For the first matrix it is simpler to use `vmatrix`.
- `node style ge` is changed so that the text is aligned properly
- `ampersand replacement` is needed to use to use a Ti*k*Z matrix inside the `align` environment.
- Change baseline of the matrix to align with second row.
- Use `'` instead of `^{\prime}`
- Shorten the arrows so the arrowheads don't get lost in the vertical lines. I made a new style `myarrow` for this purpose.
- Use `above right=` and `below right=` for placement of the signs.
- Minus signs should be in mathmode: `$-$` for the labels. (Plus signs should probably be also, but they look the same.)

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz, amsmath}
\usetikzlibrary{matrix, arrows.meta}

\tikzset{node style ge/.style={text width=2em, text centered, text depth=1.5ex, text height=3ex, inner sep=0},
    myarrow/.style={->, shorten <=1mm, shorten >=1mm}}

\begin{document}

\begin{align*}
    \begin{vmatrix}
        y & y' & y'' \\
        e^{-t} & -e^{-t} & e^{-t} \\
        e^t & e^t & e^t 
    \end{vmatrix}
    &=\begin{tikzpicture}[baseline=(A-2-1.base)]    
        \matrix (A) [matrix of math nodes, nodes = {node style ge}, column sep=0 mm, ampersand replacement=\&, inner sep=1.5pt] 
        { y \& y' \& y''\& y \& y' \\
            1 \& -1 \& 1 \& 1 \& -1 \\
            1 \& 1 \& 1 \& 1 \& 1 \\
        };       
        \draw[myarrow] (A-3-1.south west) -- (A-1-3.north east)node[above right=-1.5mm] {$-$};        
        \draw[myarrow] (A-3-2.south west) -- (A-1-4.north east)node[above right=-1.5mm] {$-$};
        \draw[myarrow] (A-3-3.south west) -- (A-1-5.north east)node[above right=-1.5mm] {$-$};
        \draw[myarrow] (A-1-1.north west) -- (A-3-3.south east)node[below right=-1.5mm] {$+$};
        \draw[myarrow] (A-1-2.north west) -- (A-3-4.south east)node[below right=-1.5mm] {$+$};
        \draw[myarrow] (A-1-3.north west) -- (A-3-5.south east)node[below right=-1.5mm] {$+$};      
        \draw[black] (A-1-1.north west) -- (A-3-1.south west);
        \draw[black] (A-1-4.north west) -- (A-3-4.south west);
    \end{tikzpicture} \\
 &=(-y+y'+y'')-(-y''+y+y') \\
 &=0 \\
 &\Rightarrow y''=y
\end{align*}

\end{document}
```